# How to get result from pickMedia android?

Tags: android

I have an activity where the user can add up to four photos individually. This is what the activity looks like

[image]

I have succeeded in getting the URI from the photo picker and using it to change the image in one of the boxes but the solution doesn't work with all four. For the solution to work with all four, I need a function that takes the URI and the photoID as arugments. I have tried to pass a photoId variable to the photo picker but that has not worked so far. I could have different functions for each of the four buttons but that would definitely be bad practice

```
val pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
        if (uri != null) {
            Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Selected URI: $uri")
        } else {
            Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
        }
    }
```

This is the code I have for allowing the user to select a photo from their gallery. Is it possible for pickMedia to accept arguments and return values?

```
val uri = pickMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
```

Also, would it be possible to do something like this?

I am quite new to Kotlin and I'm still getting used to the syntax

Comment: using pickMedia.launch() and when a result arrive store it in view model and observe that from LiveData or flow to show in UI

Comment: What code should I use to get the result? Should I be using onActivityResult()?

Comment: The code you've shown is _already_ the callback you get with the Uri that was selected - that's the `uri ->` in that code snippet. What more did you want?

Comment: i added a code snippet is this what your searching for..?

Answer (score 0):

```
private val registerForActivityResult = registerForActivityResult(ImagePicker()){ uri->
    viewModel.setUri(uri)
}
```

call this function when u want to pick picture or media in button click or somewhere else

```
 private fun getNewPicture() {
        registerForActivityResult.launch(Unit)
    }
```

Comment: I have added some details to the question